# Equivalent of unix command "type" in command prompt

Tags: command-line, shell

In Unix or Linux, `type <arguement>` provides information about how `argument` would be interpreted if used as a command. Is there any equivalent in command prompt (or in power shell as well).

I have seen few web pages which provides unix equivalents of command prompt commands (examples [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/ap-doslinux.html) and [here](https://www.lemoda.net/windows/windows2unix/windows2unix.html)). What is the most exhaustive list you have come across?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for that, it gave a solution for powershell, but I was able to figure out that `type` is similar to `which`, and i searched for command prompt equivalent for `which` which took me to the perfect link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line